# Hibernate search not updating the index for a view, when view is updated on database

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, hibernate-search, elasticsearch-5, nhibernate-search

In my project we are using Lucene and Hibernate Search/ORM 5.9.2. It works perfectly fine if a table is updated on database, same changes are reflected on ES indexes. But the index for a database view is not updated. Values are present under the database but not under the indexes.

What corresponding strategy/logic do I need to implement this through Hibernate search?

For any of the code referencing my implementation could be found under [implemented code under the Java files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51835264/typeahead-search-not-working-for-multiple-wordswith-space-through-lucene-hiber).

Further, Lets assume I've 2 classes A & B and C is the view for A+B. And I'm storing C in my elastic indexes. Once A & B are updated under the Database, is it possible C will get updated? As I'm using Hibernate search+lucene annotations.

When a table is updated under database through Hibernate entities, Hibernate search is updating the same under the indexes. But this behavior is not happening for views as they are updated on the SQL Server side. Could this be achieved through Lucene/Hibernate search?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate Search is operating at the entity level. So it does not see the changes you make directly in your database.

For Hibernate Search to manage your index, you need to rely on entities.

There's really no option for it to do things differently as this is what it has been designed for.

If the changes are made to entities, you can implement your own listener layer to deal with C or make C an entity and implement a trigger dropping the update queries on it if your database can do it.

If the changes are made directly to the database, then you're out of luck with Hibernate Search. Or you have to trigger some service in your app, every time you make a change to the database to trigger the indexing.

BTW, do you need this view at the database level? Because if you only need it at the Elasticsearch level, you can make C a proper entity having a `@OneToOne` to A and B and index the content of A and B using `@IndexedEmbedded` and `@ContainedIn` on the other side. That would solve your issue with native Hibernate Search.

I think I would try something like:

```
 @Entity
 @Indexed
 public class C {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     private Long id;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")
     // you might need a prefix if some fields are common between a and b
     @IndexedEmbedded
     private A a;

     @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b")
     // you might need a prefix if some fields are common between a and b
     @IndexedEmbedded
     private B b;
 }
```

Then in A (same for B):

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class A {
    // the existing content of your A class

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @ContainedIn
    private C c;

    public setC(C c) {
        if ( c != null ) {
            c.setA( this );
        }
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

Then when first creating A and B, you also need to create a C and inject it in A and B:

```
C c = new C();
a.setC( c );
b.setC( c );

em.persist( a );
em.persist( c );
```

Once this is done, whenever you update A or B, C should be reindexed thanks to the `@ContainedIn` annotation.

Comment: Thank you, Guillaume.
I only need this for searching purpose on ES side. Will definitely try your solution.

Comment: Please correct me if i'm wrong. By your statement, you mean to say I do not have to create a new database table, instead just create a java pojo class C containing the reference to A and B. with A having the reference to C with '@IndexedEmbedded' and C having '@ContainedIn' reference for the A attribute under it.
Please elaborate.

Comment: You need C to be an entity, so yes you need a table for it.

Comment: Added some more info to the answer. Take the time to read it and understand it before implementing it.

Comment: See the additional code I posted in the answer. You will need C to be an entity if you want it to be managed by Search but you can make it just being a very simple one with an id if you don't need all the fields in the view and be done with it. The `@IndexedEmbedded` will take care of including all the fields of A and C in the index.

Comment: now I've implemented the save part. On adding new record I implemented the way you suggested. Now the new record is found under the ES DB. But on updating the same record, its creating a new record for just 'C', will I have to persist/update all the three again from my update method. As I did for save, but as you suggested, we only need to do this once and later on the `@containedIn` will take care for update,insert and delete. But that's not happening. I'm adding the code I used for persisting the data in the question.